# How do i access map type object with values as array in mantine form

Tags: reactjs, react-forms, mantine

I am using Mantine form. Form has a map with key as string and array as value.

```
export interface Parent {   assignedFieldsMap: Map<string, Field[]>; }

export interface Field {   id: string,   name: string }
```

How do i access name element of field?
but did not work.

Thanks in advance

I have tried `form.getInputProps('assignedFieldsMap.1-1.0.name')`. Here 1-1 is the key and 0 is the index and name is field member variable.